# Python Regular expression only matches once

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a simple markdown to latex converter, just to learn python and basic regex, but I'm stuck trying to figure out why the below code doesn't work:

```
re.sub (r'\[\*\](.*?)\[\*\]: ?(.*?)$',  r'\\footnote{\2}\1', s, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

I want to convert something like:

```
s = """This is a note[*] and this is another[*]
[*]: some text
[*]: other text"""
```

to:

```
This is a note\footnote{some text} and this is another\footnote{other text}
```

this is what I got (from using my regex above):

```
This is a note\footnote{some text} and this is another[*]

[*]: note 2
```

Why is the pattern only been matched once?

### EDIT:

I tried the following lookahead assertion:

```
re.sub(r'\[\*\](?!:)(?=.+?\[\*\]: ?(.+?)$',r'\\footnote{\1}',flags=re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
#(?!:) is to prevent [*]: to be matched
```

now it matches all the footnotes, however they're not matched correctly.

```
s = """This is a note[*] and this is another[*]
[*]: some text
[*]: other text"""
```

is giving me

```
This is a note\footnote{some text} and this is another\footnote{some text}
[*]: note 1
[*]: note 2
```

Any thoughts about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you can't match the same characters several times. Once a character is matched, it is consumed by the regex engine and can't be reused for an other match.

A (general) workaround consists to capture overlapped parts inside a lookahead assertion with capture groups. But it can't be done in your case because there is no way to differentiate which note is associated with the placeholder.

A more simple way can be to extract all the notes first in a list and then to replace each placeholder with a callback. Example:

```
import re

s='''This is a note[*] and this is another[*]
[*]: note 1
[*]: note 2'''

# text and notes are separated
[text,notes] = re.split(r'((?:\r?\n\[\*\]:[^\r\n]*)+$)', s)[:-1]

# this generator gives the next replacement string 
def getnote(notes):
    for note in re.split(r'\r?\n\[\*\]: ', notes)[1:]:
        yield r'\footnote{{{}}}'.format(note)

note = getnote(notes)

res = re.sub(r'\[\*\]', lambda m: note.next(), text)
print res
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
And how should I do it? With a lookahead assertion?

Comment: sorry, i think i was misunderstood, i do not need the note number, actually the note can be any text, (see my edit)
so there's no way to achieve this with regex?

Comment: What @Casimir has said should be correct, you can not done that by using a single regex, the best and easy solution maybe use regex to catch pattern at line 2,3 in you example then put them into list then search `[*]` in the first line one by one then replace them with data in your list.

Comment: @AfonsoSilva: Note that this assumes that *"all is for the best in this, the best of all possible worlds"* since the number of notes and the number of place holders must be the same.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is, once your regex consumes a part of the string, it doesn't reconsiders it in match. So, after first replacement, it won't go back to match the 2nd `[*]`, because that has already been consumed.

What you'll need here is a loop, doing replacement until you find the match. Something like this:

```
>>> str = 'This is a note[*] and this is another[*]\n\
... [*]: note 1\n\
... [*]: note 2'
>>> reg = r'(.*?)\[\*\](.*?)\[\*\]: (note \d)(.*)'
>>> 
>>> while re.search(reg, str, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL):
...     str = re.sub(reg, r'\1\\footnote{\3}\2\4', str, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
... 
>>> 
>>> str
'This is a note\\footnote{note 1} and this is another\\footnote{note 2}\n\n'
```

You can tweak the regex a bit to get rid of trailing newlines in the resulting string. Ah! and also, you can pre-compile the regex, using `re.compile`.

Comment: thanks, that worked, however i was trying to avoid the loop, because the main idea was to have a list of rules and applying them directly to the text, but thanks anyway

Comment: also, i don't need to know the note number, it was just an example, actually it can be any text, so the part: '(note \d)' is not necessary at all

Comment: @AfonsoSilva Ok, then you can change that to `[^\r\n]*`. Newline negated match would require change, but you got the idea.